# Finding the mean of a column after grouping by multiple other columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(rep(101, 8),
              rep(102, 8)),
  Run = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  Conditions = c(rep(c('SIN', 'SIN', 'SRN', 'SRN'), 4)),
  Score = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
)
```

How can I find the mean of `Score` by `Subject` and `Conditions`? The output should look like this:

```
solution <- data.frame(
  Subject = c(101, 101, 102, 102),
  Conditions = c(rep(c('SIN', 'SRN'),2)),
  Score = c(1.5,1.5,3.5,3.5)
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why not simply `example |> summarize(Score = mean(Score), .by = c(Subject, Conditions))`?

Comment: You're right! I completely missed that. Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update after clarification:**

```
library(dplyr) #>1.1.0

example %>%
  summarise(Mean_Score = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE), .by=c(Subject, Conditions))

 Subject Conditions Mean_Score
1     101        SIN        1.5
2     101        SRN        1.5
3     102        SIN        3.5
4     102        SRN        3.5
```

**First answer:**
First we calculate the mean after grouping by `Subject, Run, Conditions` then we ungroup and group by Subject to filter for the first and last entry and finally we remove column `Run`:

```
library(dplyr) #>1.1.0

example %>%
  summarise(Mean_Score = mean(Score, na.rm = TRUE), .by=c(Subject, Run, Conditions)) %>% 
  filter(row_number()==1 | row_number()==n(), .by = Subject) %>% 
  select(-Run)
```

```
  Subject Conditions Mean_Score
1     101        SIN          1
2     101        SRN          2
3     102        SIN          3
4     102        SRN          4
```

Comment: Hi @TarJae, thank you! I made an edit to desired output. I meant to group by `Subject` and `Conditions` only without `Run`. What would be the solution then?

Comment: Ok then it is much easier, I will update the code. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggregate` if you work with base R

```
> aggregate(Score ~ Subject + Conditions, example, mean)
  Subject Conditions Score
1     101        SIN   1.5
2     102        SIN   3.5
3     101        SRN   1.5
4     102        SRN   3.5
```